# laravel eloquent search query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a input form for search where user can post **name or email** to search items.but i don't know what should be the mysql eloquent query for this specific search.

I have tried

```
    $email_or_name = Input::get('email_or_name');

    $result = Marriage::where('name','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%') or ->where('email','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%')->get();
```

its gives the following exception

```
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

then i have tried

```
$result = Marriage::where('name','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%') or Marriage::where('email','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%')->get();
```

if i put **email** address for search,it gives **No result**,

but if i put **name**,then it produce the desired results.So i suspect that the portion after the `or` in the **query** is not working.If i am right , then what should be correct **mysql eloquent query** for this type of search,

Answer (score 10):

You can't just throw in an `or` somewhere. However there is a method `orWhere()`:

```
$result = Marriage::where('name','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%')
                ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$email_or_name.'%')
                ->get();
```